# See std::cout of .exe

Tags: windows, command-line, msbuild, cmake, exe

I have a .exe file that I've compiled on windows. But when I run it from the command line I don't see any of the things my program outputs to std::cout or std::cerr. The program runs and continues to run even after the command line returns to the prompt (it's a GUI program and doesn't quit until I press the quit button). How can I see the output of my program?

I'm using cmake to make a visual studio project which I then compile with msbuild.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest approach is to rebuild the program as a console application.  The option to `link.exe` needs to be `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` instead of `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`; presumably there is a straightforward way of specifying this in cmake.

This change shouldn't affect your GUI at all, but it will cause Windows to allocate a console if the process isn't already associated with one.  Also, command line shells will usually wait for console applications to exit before continuing.

The other approach is to call [`AllocConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944.aspx) to explicitly create a new console, or [`AttachConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681952.aspx) if you want to use an existing one.  Or, of course, you could send the output to a log file.

*Additional*

According to a Google search, you can build the program as a console application by adding the following line to your source code:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE")
```

This is probably the easiest solution.  You can put it in an `#if` block if you only want the console for debug builds.

See also [CMake: How to use different ADD_EXECUTABLE for debug build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054734/cmake-how-to-use-different-add-executable-for-debug-build)

Comment: Where can I specify the /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE option? Is that in my .sln file?

Answer (score 8):

One way to see the output is to run:

```
program.exe > output.txt
```

and then monitor that file for the output. Or use a pipe to view it:

```
program.exe | find /v ""
```

To also monitor the error output you could use

```
program.exe > output.txt 2>&1

program.exe 2>&1 | find /v ""
```

I figured it out based on the documentation by [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) that leaves a lot to the imagination and from the 
much more practical examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273866/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-only-stderr-to-stdout-not-combine-the-two-so-it-can) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913119/in-windows-whats-the-difference-between-21-and-21).

This helps me see "hidden" stdout and stderr messages from my (and other peoples) windows applications. It's interesting to see what messages have been left in some programs, but usually aren't seen.

Comment: I've since switched almost entirely to using linux. However, I'd like to add a not that pycharm is a readily available gui program that spits out a lot of output if it is run at the terminal/command prompt that wouldn't be seen if you just click on it.

Answer (score 5):

[Harry Johnston's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10545408/366904) is spot-on if you want to *permanently* alter your application to display this information. I would recommend the latter approach he suggests, because switching your app to targeting the console subsystem will cause it to *always* allocate and display a console window on startup, even if you don't want it to.

However, I notice that you mention you want to display output from `std::cerr`, which implies that you might be only interested in this information for debugging purposes. In that case, my recommendation would be to call the [`OutputDebugString` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx) instead of outputting to either `std::cout` or `std::cerr`. Then, you can use a little utility like [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) to monitor the debug output of your application. Everything it sends to the `OutputDebugString` function will be displayed in the DebugView window.

If you want to use this setup with minimal changes to your existing code base, you can actually redirect the output of streams like `std::cout` and `std::cerr` to the debugger, just as if you'd called the `OutputDebugString` function. Advice on how to do this can be found in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73286/capturing-cout-in-visual-studio-2005-output-window) and in [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20140825203329/http://blog.tomaka17.com/2011/07/redirecting-cerr-and-clog-to-outputdebugstring/).

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't support dual mode. Which means that when you run gui, you cannot get output to your console that you run the app from.

Comment: Actually, there's nothing stopping a console application from presenting a GUI, and it is also possible for a GUI application to send output to the console it was launched from - but it has to do so deliberately, it doesn't "just happen".

Comment: @Harry I assume you would present the questioner with a solution, so I can learn too?

Comment: This answer seems to just be wrong. Do you have any references supporting your statement?