# Redirection standard error & ouput streams is postponed

Tags: windows, perl, redirect, cmd

I need to redirect output & error streams from one Windows process (GNU make.exe executing armcc toolchain) to some filter written on perl. The command I am running is:

```
Make Release 2>&1 | c:\cygwin\bin\perl ../tools/armfilt.pl
```

The compilation process throws out some prints which should be put then to `STDOUT` after some modifications. But I encountered a problem: all prints generated by the make are actually postponed till end of the make's process and only then are shown to a user. So, my questions are:

1. Why has it happen? I have tried to change the second process (perl.exe) priority from "Normal" to "Above normal" but it didn't help...
2. How to overcome this problem?
3. I think that one of possible workarounds may be to send only `STDERR` prints to the perl (that is what I actually need), not `STDOUT+STDERR`. But I don't know how to do it in Windows.

The Microsoft explanation concerning pipe operator usage says:

> The pipe operator (|) takes the output (by **default, STDOUT**) of one
>   command and directs it into the input (by default, STDIN) of another
>   command.

But how to change this default STDOUT piping is not explained. Is it possible at all?

Comment: `make.exe 1>output.txt 2>errors.txt`

Comment: @loldop - redirection the stdout & stderr to different files is not a problem. The problem is to redirect stderr only using the pipe (|) to another process...

Comment: yeah, I understand your problem. Maybe really better to write wrapper-script over this? STDERR to file, then read it, why not?

Comment: maybe this question can help? [stderr and stdout tricks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273866/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-only-stderr-to-stdout-not-combine-the-two-so-it-can)