# Appearance of non-existing character in batch file

Tags: batch-file, set

(Variables changed)

I used command
`set /p A_Aaaaaa=<aaaaaa.aaa` and it says that such file doesn't exist, so I deleted `@echo off` from top of file, and searched for line that causes this error. I don't know why, but if I look into CMD that started script, it seem that above `set /p` command is understood as

`set /p A_Aaaaaa= 0<aaaaaa.aaa` I don't know where the `(space)0` does from, any simple idea?

Ask any informations, be aware that I will change variables though.

Comment: This is one of most strange errors I ever met, because if this `set /p` commando is started manually from CMD, it works. If pasted into file... it doesn't... operate it...

Comment: How do you start the batch file? What directory is current at that time? Is it the same directory that contains the `aaaaaa.aaa` file? Also, does the batch file change the current directory in the process? On the other hand, all those would not matter if you specified the full path to the file that the `set /p` command was reading from.

Comment: Actually problem is solved by Microsoft, but thank you for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0` is `STDIN`, the standard input stream. Usually `set/p` reads its input from the user (standard input). With the code `set /p A_Aaaaaa=<aaaaaa.aaa` you redirect the output from `aaaaaa.aaa` to the standard input, so `set/p` can read it. This behavior does not depend on whether the file exists or not. You can read something about streams [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12274145/2098699).

Comment: No f***, does this one, simple space, really, really matter?!

Comment: Ehm, the link you gave, I cannot find anything useful in it... it about strange signs I am not working with (I won't work with them either I think)

Comment: `This behavior does not depend on whether the file exists or not.` 100% it exist. Because its load from internet (VBS) and every user has one... so... A_Aaaaaa, is never empty... (only at begin but thats A LOT of lines before)

Comment: Yes, make a file, e.g. `echo(blah>aaaaaa.aaa`.

Comment: Maybe the filename being used has long filename elements and needs to be double quoted.

Comment: @Endoro Why should I? I mean, the file is really there, with real data I need to retrieve... foxidrive Length is same, its 6 characters long with 3 characters long extension.

Comment: If the system means, there is no file then is there no file. Maybe the file name is wrong or the path. I don't know, here it works.

Comment: Its really there! I typed same commands in CMD manually, this path works because I wrote echo %A_Aaaaaa% and content came out.

Comment: No, `echo` is the command for variables, eg. `echo %path%`. for files use `type aaaaaa.aaa`.

Comment: So `set /p Var=<Path1.xyz` and then `type %Var%`?
Or second one `set Var=Path1.xyz` and then `type %Var%`?

Comment: By the way I don't need aaaaaa.aaa for echoing, I need it to check if it matches other code inside program itself.

Comment: read the line from file: `set /p Var=<Path1.xyz`, echo the line: `echo %var%`. If you want to see the file without a variable: `type Path1.xyz`.

Comment: I don't want to see file, I want to compare file content to code in program itself like `if "%var1%"=="%var2%" DO SOMETHING`. It started to be offtopic. The question isn't how to read data, the problem is `set /p Var=<Path1.xyz` that doesn't work...