# Order of redirection operators in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

`foo.exe > out.txt 2>&1` will redirect both stdout and stderr to a file.

However `foo.exe 2>&1 > out.txt` will redirect stdout to a file and stderr to console. Why do they behave differently? Aren't they both saying the same thing (send stderr to stdout and send stdout to file)?

Comment: please look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273866/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-only-stderr-to-stdout-not-combine-the-two-so-it-can).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the redirection from STDOUT first, and then set the 2>&1 redirection.  It redirects STDERR to the place that STDOUT is going.