# Batch set output and error of a command to separate variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-7, io-redirection

In windows 7 batch (cmd.exe command-line), I am trying to redirect the standard output (stdout) and standard error (stderr) of a command to separate variables (so the 1st variables is set to the output, and the 2nd variable is set to the error (if any)) without using any temporary files. I have tried and tried with no success at this.

So, what would be a **working** way to set the output and error of a command to separate variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could go for two nested `for /F` loops, where the inner one captures the standard output and the outer one captures the redirected error. Since the inner one instances a new `cmd` process, the captured text cannot just be assigned to a variable, because it will be lost after execution finishes. Rather I precede every line with `|` and just echo it to the standard output. The outer loop detects the leading `|` and separates the lines accordingly:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "STDOUT="
set "STDERR="
(set LF=^
%=empty line=%
)
for /F "delims=" %%E in ('
    2^>^&1 ^(^
        for /F "delims=" %%O in ^('^
            command_line^
        '^) do @^(^
            echo ^^^|%%O^
        ^)^
    ^)
') do (
    set "LINE=%%E"
    if "!LINE:~,1!"=="|" (
        set "STDOUT=!STDOUT!!LINE:~1!!LF!"
    ) else (
        set "STDERR=!STDERR!!LINE!!LF!"
    )
)
echo ** STDOUT **!LF!!STDOUT!
echo ** STDERR **!LF!!STDERR!
endlocal
exit /B
```

The following restrictions apply to the code:

- empty lines are ignored;
- lines that begin with a semicolon `;` are ignored;
- exclamation marks `!` are lost, because delayed environment variable expansion is enabled;
- lines that begin with a pipe character `|` may be assigned wrongly;
- the overall size of data must not exceed 8190 bytes;

All of those limitations are true for both standard output and standard error.

---

#### Edit:

Here is an improved variant of the above code. The issues concerning empty lines and lines beginning with a semicolon `;` are resolved, the other restrictions still remain:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "STDOUT="
set "STDERR="
(set LF=^
%=empty line=%
)
for /F "delims=" %%E in ('
    2^>^&1 ^(^
        for /F "delims=" %%O in ^('^
            command_line ^^^^^^^| findstr /N /R "^"^
        '^) do @^(^
            echo ^^^^^^^|%%O^
        ^)^
    ^) ^| findstr /N /R "^"
') do (
    set "LINE=%%E"
    set "LINE=!LINE:*:=!"
    if "!LINE:~,1!"=="|" (
        set "STDOUT=!STDOUT!!LINE:*:=!!LF!"
    ) else (
        set "STDERR=!STDERR!!LINE!!LF!"
    )
)
echo ** STDOUT **!LF!!STDOUT!
echo ** STDERR **!LF!!STDERR!
endlocal
exit /B
```

The `findstr` command is used to precede every single line with a line number plus `:`, so no line appears empty to `for /F`; this prefix is removed later on, of course. This change also solves the `;` issue implicitly.

Because of the nested piping into `findstr`, multiple escaping is required to hide the `|` character as long as its piping function is actually needed.

Comment: This cannot possibly work. Besides the fact that each of your IN() lines must use line continuation `^` at the end, the fundamental idea is flawed. Each IN() command is executed in a new cmd.exe process. Any variable you define within the process will disappear once the process terminates. So your parent script cannot see the STDOUT variable - it will not survive.

Comment: That came into my mind as well, @dbenham, and of course my first test failed; so I changed the strategy a bit and updated my answer accordingly... I think I will rework it once again to overcome all the listed restrictions (except the size limit), because it should be quite easy (except the `!` issue)... thanks anyway for your hints!!

Comment: +1 Ooh - very clever! You can support nearly 8190 bytes per line by using "arrays". Use FINDSTR as in my answer to avoid the `;` EOL issue, and to get the array index, and to solve the empty line issue. You can handle any leading character by prefixing both stdout and stderr with unique flag characters. I would use `+` for stdout and `-` for stderr. You can preserve `!` by careful toggling of delayed expansion. However, as creative as your solution is, I believe the temp file solution is faster, and it sure is a lot simpler to implement.

Comment: Also, you do not need to escape `'`, `(`, or `@`.

Comment: Never mind about my `+`,`-` idea. I don't see how to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, @dbenham; see my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34488461/8), where most issues are resolved now; I also fixed the superfluous escaping (except `^(`, because it looks more logical to me together with `^)`); I'm still searching for a fix of the `!` issue, I'll update the code as soon as it's done...

Comment: Very good. See the end of [my edited answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34489424/1012053) for methods to preserve `!`. It is butt ugly, but it works.

Comment: Eureka - all but size limitation eliminated. See my updated answer yet again.

Comment: Wow, you are genius, @dbenham!! so can I expect anpother update tomorrow due to the size limit?? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

First off, batch does not have a simple method to capture multi-line output like unix shell scripting. You can use FOR /F to build a multi-line value line by line, but the total length is limited to < 8191 bytes, and the syntax is awkward. Or you could use FOR /F to capture multiple lines in a simulated array of variables.

With regard to your question, there is no way to independently capture both stdout and stderr without using at least one temporary file. ***EDIT:*** *WRONG, [aschipfl found a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34488461/1012053). However, the temp file is faster, and a whole lot simpler.*

Here is a simple demonstration that uses a file to capture stderr. I'm assuming you want to capture at most one line of stdout and/or stderr.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('yourCommand 2^>err.log`) do set "out=%%A"
<err.log set /p "err="
del err.log
```

Here is a more complex example that captures an array of lines for both stdout and stderr. Here I assume that none of the lines of output begin with `:`. The FINDSTR prefixes each line with a line number followed by a `:`, and the FOR /F parses out the line number to be used as an "array" index, as well as the value after the `:`.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set /a out.cnt=err.cnt=0
for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%A in ('yourCommand 2^>err.log ^| findstr /n "^"') do (
  set "out.%%A=%%B"
  set "out.cnt=%%A"
)
for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" err.log') do (
  set "err.%%A=%%B"
  set "err.cnt=%%A"
)

:: Display the results
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo ** STDOUT **
for /l %%N in (1 1 %out.cnt%) do echo(!out.%%N!
echo ** STDERR **
for /l %%N in (1 1 %err.cnt%) do echo(!err.%%N!
```

***2nd Edit***

Additional code is required if you want to properly handle output that begins with `:`.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set /a out.cnt=err.cnt=0
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('yourCommand 2^>err.log ^| findstr /n "^"') do for /f "delims=:" %%N in ("%%A") do (
  set "ln=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "delims=" %%B in (^""!ln:*:=!"^") do (
    endlocal
    set "out.%%N=%%~B"
    set "out.cnt=%%N"
  )
)
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" err.log') do for /f "delims=:" %%N in ("%%A") do (
  set "ln=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "delims=" %%B in (^""!ln:*:=!"^") do (
    endlocal
    set "err.%%N=%%~B"
    set "err.cnt=%%N"
  )
)

:: Display the results
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo ** STDOUT **
for /l %%N in (1 1 %out.cnt%) do echo(!out.%%N!
echo ** STDERR **
for /l %%N in (1 1 %err.cnt%) do echo(!err.%%N!
```

---

Below I have adapted aschipfl's 2nd code that avoids using a temp file so that it preserves `!` characters. The code just gets uglier and uglier ;-)

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "STDOUT="
SET "STDERR="
for /f "delims=" %%E in (
   '2^>^&1 (for /f "delims=" %%O in ('^
      yourCommand^
   ^^^^^^^| findstr /n /r "^"'^) do @(echo ^^^^^^^|%%O^)^) ^| findstr /n /r "^"'
) do (
   set "ln=%%E"
   setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
   set "ln=x!ln:*:=!"
   set "ln=!ln:\=\s!"
   if "!ln:~0,2!"=="x|" (
      set "ln=!ln:~0,-1!"
      for /f "delims=" %%A in (^""!STDOUT!"^") do for /f "delims=" %%B in (^""!ln:*:=!"^") do (
        endlocal
        set "STDOUT=%%~A%%~B\n"
      )
   ) else (
      for /f "delims=" %%A in (^""!STDERR!"^") do for /f "delims=" %%B in (^""!ln:~1!"^") do (
        endlocal
        set "STDERR=%%~A%%~B\n"
      )
   )
)
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%L in (^"^
%= empty line =%
^") do (
  if defined STDOUT (
    set "STDOUT=!STDOUT:\n=%%~L!"
    set "STDOUT=!STDOUT:\s=\!"
    set "STDOUT=!STDOUT:~0,-1!"
  )
  if defined stderr (
    set "STDERR=!STDERR:\n=%%~L!"
    set "STDERR=!STDERR:\s=\!"
    set "STDERR=!STDERR:~0,-1!"
  )
)

echo ** STDOUT **
echo(!STDOUT!
echo ** STDERR **
echo(!STDERR!
exit /b
```

It is a bit simpler if the result is stored in arrays instead of a pair of strings.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set /a out.cnt=err.cnt=1
for /f "delims=" %%E in (
   '2^>^&1 (for /f "delims=" %%O in ('^
      yourCommand^
   ^^^^^^^| findstr /n /r "^"'^) do @(echo ^^^^^^^|%%O^)^) ^| findstr /n /r "^"'
) do (
   set "ln=%%E"
   setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
   set "ln=x!ln:*:=!"
   if "!ln:~0,2!"=="x|" (
      set "ln=!ln:~0,-1!"
      for %%N in (!out.cnt!) do for /f "delims=" %%A in (^""!ln:*:=!"^") do (
        endlocal
        set "out.%%N=%%~A"
        set /a out.cnt+=1
      )
   ) else (
      for %%N in (!err.cnt!) do for /f "delims=" %%A in (^""!ln:~1!"^") do (
        endlocal
        set "err.%%N=%%~A"
        set /a err.cnt+=1
      )
   )
)
set /a out.cnt-=1, err.cnt-=1
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

echo ** STDOUT **
for /l %%N in (1 1 %out.cnt%) do echo(!out.%%N!
echo ** STDERR **
for /l %%N in (1 1 %err.cnt%) do echo(!err.%%N!
exit /b
```

I know many people try to avoid temp files, but in this case I think it is counter productive. Tests have shown that temp files can be much faster than processing the result of a command with a FOR /F loop when the output is very large. And the temp file solution is so much simpler. So I would definitely use the temp file solution.

But finding a non-temp file solution is an interesting challenge. Kudos to aschipfl for working out the complicated escape sequences.

---

***3rd (final?) Edit***

At last, here is a solution that eliminates all restrictions, other than each captured line of output must be less than around 8180 bytes.

I could have put the entire code in one big loop, but then the escape sequences would have been a nightmare. Figuring out the escape sequences is much simpler when I break the code into smaller subroutines.

I capture the stdout and stderr for a bunch of ECHO commands found in the :test routine at the bottom.

```
::
:: Script to demonstrate how to run one or more commands
:: and capture stdout in one array and stderr in another array,
:: without using a temporary file.
::
:: The command(s) to run should be placed in the :test routine at the bottom.
::

@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1" equ ":out" goto :out
if "%~1" equ ":err" goto :err
if "%~1" equ ":test" goto :test

set /a out.cnt=err.cnt=0

:: Runs :err, which runs :out, which runs :test
:: stdout is captured in out array, and stderr in err array.
for /f "delims=. tokens=1*" %%A in ('^""%~f0" :err^"') do (
  for /f "delims=:" %%N in ("%%B") do (
    set "ln=%%B"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "delims=" %%L in (^""!ln:*:=!"^") do (
      endlocal
      set "%%A.%%N=%%~L"
      set "%%A.cnt=%%N"
    )
  )
)

:: Show results
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo ** STDOUT **
for /l %%N in (1 1 %out.cnt%) do echo(!out.%%N!
echo(
echo ** STDERR **
for /l %%N in (1 1 %err.cnt%) do echo(!err.%%N!
exit /b


:err  :: 1) Run the :out code, which swaps stdout with stderr
      :: 2) Prefix stream 1 (stderr) output with err.###:  where ### = line number
      :: 3) Rredirect stream 2 (stdout) to combine with stream 1 (stderr)
2>&1 (for /f "delims=" %%A in ('^""%~f0" :out^|findstr /n "^"^"') do echo err.%%A)
exit /b


:out  :: 1) Run the :test code.
      :: 2) Prefix stream 1 (stdout) output with out.###:  where ### = line number
      :: 3) Swap stream 1 (stdout) with stream 2 (stderr)
3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 (for /f "delims=" %%A in ('^""%~f0" :test^|findstr /n "^"^"') do echo out.%%A)
exit /b


:test :: Place the command(s) to run in this routine
    echo STDOUT line 1 with empty line following
    echo(
>&2 echo STDERR line 1 with empty line following
>&2 echo(
    echo STDOUT line 3 with poison characters "(<^&|!%%>)" (^<^^^&^|!%%^>)
>&2 echo STDERR line 3 with poison characters "(<^&|!%%>)" (^<^^^&^|!%%^>)
    echo err.4:STDOUT line 4 spoofed as stderr - No problem!
>&2 echo out.4:STDERR line 4 spoofed as stdout - No problem!
    echo :STDOUT line 5 leading colon preserved
>&2 echo :STDERR line 5 leading colon preserved
    echo ;STDOUT line 6 default EOL of ; not a problem
>&2 echo ;STDERR line 6 default EOL of ; not a problem
exit /b
```

-- OUTPUT --

```
** STDOUT **
STDOUT line 1 with empty line following

STDOUT line 3 with poison characters "(<^&|!%>)" (<^&|!%>)
err.4:STDOUT line 4 spoofed as stderr - No problem!
:STDOUT line 5 leading colon preserved
;STDOUT line 6 default EOL of ; not a problem

** STDERR **
STDERR line 1 with empty line following

STDERR line 3 with poison characters "(<^&|!%>)" (<^&|!%>)
out.4:STDERR line 4 spoofed as stdout - No problem!
:STDERR line 5 leading colon preserved
;STDERR line 6 default EOL of ; not a problem
```

I *still* like the temp file solution much better ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This solution works correctly as long as the lines sent to stdout does *not* start with the line number itself separated by colon.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /A out=0, err=1
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('(theCommand 1^>^&2 2^>^&3 ^| findstr /N "^"^) 2^>^&1') do (
   if "%%a" equ "!err!" (
      set "stderr[!err!]=%%b"
      set /A err+=1
   ) else (
      set /A out+=1
      if "%%b" equ "" (
         set "stdout[!out!]=%%a"
      ) else (
         set "stdout[!out!]=%%a:%%b"
      )
   )
)
set /A err-=1

echo Lines sent to Stdout:
for /L %%i in (1,1,%out%) do echo !stdout[%%i]!
echo/
echo Lines sent to Stderr:
for /L %%i in (1,1,%err%) do echo !stderr[%%i]!
```

For example, if theCommand is this .bat file:

```
@echo off
echo Line one to stdout
echo Line one to stderr >&2
echo Line two to stderr >&2
echo Line two to stdout
```

... then this is the output:

```
Lines sent to Stdout:
Line one to stdout
Line two to stdout

Lines sent to Stderr:
Line one to stderr
Line two to stderr
```

Comment: How does this work? does `findstr` process the data in stream **3**? if yes, is this another "hidden feature" of `findstr`??

Comment: @aschipfl - No, FINDSTR only processes stream 1. `1>&2 2>&3` (or `2>&3, 1>&2`) effectively swaps stdout and stderr, but only if stream 3 was not previously defined. If stream 3 might already exist, then you must use `3>&1 1>&2 2>&3`, (or `3>&2 2>&1 1>&3`). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12274145/1012053 for more info.