# How to use wintee to redirect STDERR only?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, io-redirection

I'm currently using [wintee](https://code.google.com/archive/p/wintee/) to log the result messages from testing scripts. Here's what the command looks like:

```
test_name.bat [parameters] 2>&1 | wtee log.txt
```

However, I only would like to archive STDERR to a file, while still displaying both STDOUT and STDERR to the console. The problem emerges from wintee's limitation: it seems to only fork STDIN, STDOUT, and input files.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Redirect STDOUT to stream 3 (unused stream)
2. Redirect STDERR to STDOUT
3. Redirect stream 3 (the redirected STDOUT) to STDERR

This way, the console will still display both streams' messages, while wintee will only fork the messages from (what originally was) STDERR.

However, I'm not sure whether if it's possible, as my understanding of the stream redirection is shallow. I'm trying to see if I can redirect STDOUT to STDERR using another stream in between:

```
echo Hello World! 3>&2 >3
```

However, it isn't printing anything.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible in native batch (optionally with helps of other tools)? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```vbs
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout   
On Error Resume Next

Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set File = Fso.CreateTextFile(Arg(0), True)
If err.number <> 0 then
    Outp.WriteLine "Error: " & err.number & " " & err.description & " from " & err.source
    err.clear
    wscript.exit
End If
Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
    Line=Inp.readline
    outp.writeline Line
    File.WriteLine Line
Loop
```

This Tees StdOut. Changing the 4th line to `Set Outp = Wscript.Stderr` will make it Tee StdErr.

To use `dir | cscript //nologo Tee.vbs`.

Comment: I guess there is the log file missing in the usage string, right? Anyway, if I specify one or not, I am getting error 9 (Subscript out of range); when I change `Arg(1)` to `Arg(0)`, no error arises; can you tell me why this happens? (`Arg(0)` should point to the script itself, and `Arg(1)` to the first argument, true?)

Comment: Not in VBScript. That is CMD's rules. In VBScript 1st param is arg(0). The [almost] equivalent of %~dp0 is `wscript.ScriptFullName` .

Comment: Ah, I see, that explains the error I am getting; thanks... So `Arg(1)` needs to be changed to `Arg(0)` in your script...

Comment: Yes, it is part of a larger file where Arg(0) is the sub command. So yes change.

Comment: The larger file is called filter and is here https://1drv.ms/w/s!AvqkaKIXzvDigWyNPt14cNh-m9Ji

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the `wintee` command, but I think I can help you with the redirection issue:

Instead of `test_name.bat [parameters] 2>&1 | wtee log.txt`, you should write the following:

```
(test_name.bat [parameters] 2>&1 1> con) | wtee log.txt
```

This writes the text at *STDOUT* to the console, redirects the data at *STDERR* to *STDOUT*, which is in turn passed to the `wtee` command.

Note that the console displays all original *STDOUT* before any *STDERR* data, because the former is displayed immediately, while the latter is passed through `wtee`. With pure redirection hacks it is not possible to preserve the original order which the data was returned with. <s>If you insist on that, you need to use a tool other than `wintee` which has got the required capabilities.</s> ***Edit:*** In particular, the pipe is the bottleneck, because there is only one channel, namely *STDIN*, where it passes data to. So if you insist on *STDOUT* and *SRDERR* data to be displayed in the original order while saving the data of one stream to a file, you have no other choice but to modify the script `test_name.bat` and to avoid piping.

---

I am trying to explain that using the command `dir ":"` on the left side of the pipe, which produces output at both *STDOUT* and *STDERR* (because of the invalid path `":"`):

```
D:\Data> dir ":"
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Seriel Number is 0000-0000

 Directory of D:\Data

File Not Found
```

The `File Not Found` message appears at *STDERR*, whereas the rest appears at *STDOUT* (you can prove that by redirecting like `2> nul` or `1> nul` to dismiss either of the streams).

On the right side of the pipe, I am using the command `find /V ""`, which simply passes all data it receives at *STDIN* through and displays it on the console:

```
D:\Data> dir ":" | find /V ""
File Not Found
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Seriel Number is 0000-0000

 Directory of D:\Data
```

The changed order of the console output illustrates what happens: *STDERR* is displayed immediately, whereas *STDOUT* is first passed through the pipe before being displayed.

Now let us apply the redirection `2>&1` from your command line:

```
D:\Data> (dir ":" 2>&1) | find /V ""
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Seriel Number is 0000-0000

 Directory of D:\Data

File Not Found
```

This redirects *STDERR* to *STDOUT*, so the original *STDOUT* data together with the redirected ones are piped through. Replacing `find /V ""` by `(> nul find /V "")` proves that the right side of the pipe really receives all of the data.

Now let us add the `1> con` portion, which constitutes an explicit redirection of *STDOUT* to the console:

```
D:\Data> (dir ":" 2>&1 1> con) | find /V ""
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Seriel Number is 0000-0000

 Directory of D:\Data

File Not Found
```

The output contains all of the original data. Again replacing `find /V ""` by `(> nul find /V "")` proves that this time, the right side of the pipe truly only recieves the `File Not Found` message, which was originally present at *STDERR*, but the *STDOUT* data are not piped through.

---

Just a side-note:
If you want to do something like `wintee` with pure [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), things become very complicated -- see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34486993)...